# SQLPLUS Convert NUM to Text (CHAR)

Tags: sql, sqlplus

I am running the below query and I want to convert the TESTID column from Number to Text. I tried using the TO_CHAR, however it still shows up a Number in Exponential Format (when spooling to Excel). Any Ideas?

```
SET LINESIZE 32767;
SET PAGESIZE 32767;
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET MARKUP HTML ON SPOOL ON
SPOOL D:\REJECT.xls;
Select
            TO_CHAR(rud.TESTID) AS TESTID
From
            TESTAM.TEST_DETAILS rud
/
spool off;
exit;
```

Thank You!

Comment: try to spool in csv file to check if it is because of spool or excel. `SPOOL D:\REJECT.csv`

Comment: most probably its just excel presentation format

Comment: It is due to Excel limitation, hence I was trying to convert into Text which does not get truncated in Excel. Any Ideas?